# ARM inline constraints

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, arm

Is there a way in `ARM` assembly to place the address of an array into a register?

Something similar to

```
 __asm__("movl %0,%%eax"::"r"(&array1));
```

`AT&T` syntax for `X86`

My initially [attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852314/can-we-use-address-of-operator-inline-gcc-arm-assembly?rq=1) when in manner

```
__asm__("LDR R0,%0" :: "m" (&array`)");
```

Can you give me any suggestion or point to a place where I can look in for this.

Comment: Related: [Neon C array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031124/using-c-arrays-in-inline-gcc-assembly), also [False Positive...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119201/false-positive-undefined-or-garbage-value-returned-to-caller) giving [ARM inline secrets](http://hardwarebug.org/2010/07/06/arm-inline-asm-secrets/) and [ARM constraint file](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/arm/constraints.md;hb=HEAD). An alternate is `asm("ldr r0, %0" :: "m" (array) : "r0", "memory");` should work; don't take the address.

Comment: @artlessnoise: ` error: memory input 0 is not directly addressable`
Thanks for those links!.  Maybe it is a `=0`

Comment: Please try `asm("ldr r0, %0" :: "Uq" (&array[0]) : "r0", "memory");`.  This loads the data at `array` as a 32bit value.  If you just want the *pointer*, then `asm("mov r0, %0" :: "r" (array) : "r0");` should work as Auselen suggested.  Usually the whole point of *inline* assembler is to let the compiler do the register allocation for you; so maybe I am **X-Y** confused?

Comment: Exactly! I just want the pointer!. the `address` of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
int a[10];
asm volatile("mov %r0, %[a]" : : [a] "r" (a));
```

[ARM GCC Inline Assembler Cookbook](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html) is a very good resource to get syntax right.

Look also at [Specifying Registers for Local Variables](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Reg-Vars.html) in GCC docs. You can directly specify registers for variables.

```
register int *foo asm ("a5");
```

Comment: `130     __asm__ volatile("MOV R0,%[array1]" : [array1] "=r" (array1)");`

`130:75: warning: missing terminating " character [enabled by default]`
`130:5: error: missing terminating " character`

Comment: why is it volatile? what does that mean?

Comment: sorry, fixed missing `:` in the middle. volatile is for compiler not to remove it. and in your error you have an extra `"` at the end.

Comment: I haven't. I use `VIM` and it is showing clearly that all of them are closed

Comment: @pistal added one more suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! Never seen those - interesting!